# Python annotate variable as sklearn model

Tags: python, function, scikit-learn, annotations, typing

I have a function that takes in an sklearn model as an argument. I would like to annotate the parameter to indicate that it is an sklearn model.

What I've tried:

```
def foo(model: 'Model'):
    pass
```

this returns the error `Name "Model" is not defined mypy(error)`. I then tried:

```
from typing import TypeVar

Model = TypeVar('Model')
def foo(model: Model):
    pass
```

but when I call any functions on the model (e.g. model.feature_importances_) it returns the error `"Model" has no attribute "feature_importances_" mypy(error)`

Is there any way to annotate a parameter as a custom object?

Answer (score 0):

It does seem to be possible to annotate function arguments as `sklearn` model types.

Here's an example.

```py
$ ipython
Python 3.8.10 (default, May  4 2021, 00:00:00) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.1.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import sklearn

In [2]: from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

In [3]: reg=LinearRegression()

In [4]: def foo(model: sklearn.linear_model._base.LinearRegression):
   ...:     pass

In [5]: foo(reg)

In [6]: import inspect

In [7]: inspect.getmro(type(reg))
Out[7]: 
(sklearn.linear_model._base.LinearRegression,
 sklearn.base.MultiOutputMixin,
 sklearn.base.RegressorMixin,
 sklearn.linear_model._base.LinearModel,
 sklearn.base.BaseEstimator,
 object)

In [8]: def foo(model: sklearn.base.MultiOutputMixin):
   ...:     pass

In [9]: foo(reg)

In [10]: def foo(model: sklearn.base.BaseEstimator):
    ...:     pass

In [11]: foo(reg)

In [12]:
```